# how to make date reminder in PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a database for labors resident Visa, I want to make a reminder on expiry date, if a visa expire at 1/1/2012, I Want PHP to send me reminder as email, or pop up message

EDIT

thank you guys, but let's forget about the reminder via email, let's say I created a table (ID,name,issue date,expiry date) (1,joe,11/11/2009,12/11/2011) and all data are displayed in a table.. what I want to do is, I want the color of the table row to turn red in case its expired.

I hope I explained it right..

Answer (score 2):

create a page to check the expiry date and do necessary action. set a cron job to call the page every one hour or a time suitable for you.

Search for cron job and how to setup it in your control panel using your search engine

Comment: thank you Joby, but let's forget about the reminder via email, let's say I created a table (ID,name,issue date,expiry date) (1,joe,11/11/2009,12/11/2011) and all data are displayed in a table.. what I want to do is, I want the table row color to turn red in case its expired

Comment: I think now the problem is only with presentation. While populating the table rows inside the loop check if current date greater than expiry date. if thats the case add a style attribute to tr tag with background color:red. am i helping you?

Comment: yes you are!, I will look up how to make that formula, I'm beginner in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Run a cron job every day to fetch the list of visas expiring on specific date, and send a mail to all the results.

More info about cron
http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-cron/

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the cronjob .. that make an email to you after a specific time
You can read more about cronjob from here ...

[cronjob](http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=30)

Answer (score 1):

Check this url which could be the basis of your script, and easily merged. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Setup-Your-Personal-Reminder-System-Using-PHP/1/

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep and Joby provided your solution. I would like to add this as another suggestion.

Use cron job to schedule a process that will check for visas expiring everyday. Then send an email appropriately.

To send an email easily, you can use [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) library. It has a lot of built-in facility which are ready for use.